# java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
List queryList = executeReadAllSQLQuery(queryString);
    for (Iterator i = queryList.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        Object values[] = (Object[]) i.next();
        FDetails pDetails = transform(values);
        fDList.add(pDetails);
        values = null;
    }
```

Error I am getting at line 3 : `java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;`

My transform function :

```
private FDetails transform(Object[] values) {
    FDetails Details = new FDetails();
    Details.setPb((BigDecimal)values[0]);
    Details.setPm((BigDecimal)values[1]);
    Details.setEl((BigDecimal)values[1]);
    Details.setUl((BigDecimal)values[1]);
    return BalanceDetails;
}
```

Please help me resolve these issue.

Comment: This would be more easy, if you'd use generics instead of raw types.

Comment: What's the query? It returns a single BigDecimal value per row, and not an array of objects as you think it does.

Comment: Show us the code of `executeReadAllSQLQuery(queryString);` !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
List<BigDecimal> queryList = executeReadAllSQLQuery(queryString);

FDetails details = new FDetails();
int i = 0;
details.setPb(queryList.get(i ++));
details.setPm(queryList.get(i ++));
...

fDList.add(pDetails);
```

Note: Calling `fDList.add()` inside of the loop is almost certainly wrong. The loop gets one value from the list but you want all five values from the list, create **one** instance of `FDetails` from those five values and add that single instance to `fDList` **once**

Comment: @VampireHunter: Then don't forget that other people use this site as well and they will be confused when they see questions without correct answers. Either say which of our answers was correct or post the solution.

Answer (score 3):

It's clear from error that your List queryList is in fact a list of BigDecimals. So this would be work

```
BigDecimal value = (BigDecimal) i.next();
```

but since it's not what you expect then executeReadAllSQLQuery returns wrong result

BTW for-each would look better anyway

```
for (Object obj : queryList) {
   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for replying.But if I am using BigDecimal value = (BigDecimal) i.next(); then how could I set the attributes as in transform function() as shown.

Comment: BigDecimal value = (BigDecimal) i.next(); would return me a single BigDecimal value at a time.The rows will get changed.I want to set the values for a single row in my view

Comment: @VampireHunter: Java is very reluctant to convert between types. So you need to create an object array manually, copy the values into it and then call the method with the new array.

Comment: @Vampire Hunter You should show your queryString and executeReadAllSQLQuery method

Answer (score 0):

The below line is returning you a `java.math.BigDecimal` which you are trying to cast illegaly to `Object[]`. It seems your`queryList` is a `List<java.math.BigDecimal>`.

```
i.next(); // is returning you a  java.math.BigDecimal
```

Answer (score 0):

This works very fine!. Please try this

```
    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("amt", "1000");

    System.out.println("Amount is::"
            + new BigDecimal((String) map.get("amt")));
```